# Consolidate multi column data frame based on ID using maximum date?

Tags: r

I've got the data frame as below.

```
ID     OrDATE     ExDATE          INVOICE  SHIPPED RECEIVE
1      2015-11-26 2015-11-26      20       0       0
1      2016-10-28 2016-11-14      20       0       0
2      2015-11-26 2015-11-26      20       0       0
2      2016-10-26 2016-11-14      20       0       0
3      2015-11-26 2015-11-26      30       0       0
3      2016-10-26 2016-11-14      20       0       0
```

I want to consolidate this data frame according to it's ID by using the latest date in OrDate column, however, should not accumulate INVOICE, SHIPPED or RECEIVE.

```
ID     OrDATE     ExDATE          INVOICE  SHIPPED RECEIVE
1      2016-10-28 2016-11-14      20       0       0
2      2016-10-26 2016-11-14      20       0       0
3      2016-10-26 2016-11-14      20       0       0
```

Comment: Please add some more info like the technology you are using and what efforts you've made and also edit the list of keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group by 'ID' and `slice` the row having the `max` date in 'OrDATE'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   slice(which.max(OrDATE))
# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID OrDATE     ExDATE     INVOICE SHIPPED RECEIVE
#  <int> <date>     <chr>        <int>   <int>   <int>
#1     1 2016-10-28 2016-11-14      20       0       0
#2     2 2016-10-26 2016-11-14      20       0       0
#3     3 2016-10-26 2016-11-14      20       0       0
```